# How to sort model object by object in dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssortdescriptor

I've a model object that extends from NSObject called column. Column has two fields, properties and data. Properties is an NSDictionary that stores arbitrary key/value pairs while data is an array.

Columns come in arrays and I need to sort them by a value I know will always be in properties, a value with the key ordinal_position.

I'm using the following code to sort but it always fails because there is no "ordinal_position" in the model object, only in the properties of the model object:

```
NSArray *unsortedArray = [resultStore allValues];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ordinal_position" ascending:YES] autorelease];

NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

How can I tell NSSortDescriptor to look for the property in a dictionary in the model object?

Comment: “I've a model object that extends from NSObject called column. Column has two fields, properties and data. Properties is an NSDictionary that stores arbitrary key/value pairs while data is an array.” Is there is a reason for this? It's completely opposite to how Cocoa is oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your own selector that returns an [NSComparisonResult](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparisonResult) and implement it:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareByProperty:(Column *)aColumn {
    id thisValue = [self valueForKey:@"ordinal_position"];
    id otherValue = [self valueForKey:@"ordinal_position"];

    return [thisValue compare:otherValue]; // Replace to suit your logic
}
```

Then use the NSArray method [`sortedArrayUsingSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBHAGJ):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareByProperty:)];
```

Note that your comparison method must exist on your model object, not on the class you're calling this from - the idiom is that you're comparing some given model object (`self`) to another model object (`aColumn`) from within the first object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a keyPath:

@"myDictionary.ordinal_position"